# multiple fieldables in document causes nullpointerexception

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

When i add more than one Fieldable to my Document i get a nullpointer exception(without any exception description) when i try to add the document to the indexwriter.

i only changed the fieldable method called stringvalue, to return a string.

Is it not allowed to add more fieldables, or am i missing something ?

code that might be relevant

```
    File[] files = FILES_TO_INDEX_DIRECTORY.listFiles();
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_33);
    SimpleFSDirectory d = new SimpleFSDirectory(INDEX_DIRECTORY);
    IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_33, analyzer);
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(d, iwc);

for (File file : files) {
        try
        {
        final String path = file.getCanonicalPath();
        final String name = file.getName();
        Fieldable field1 = new Fieldable()
        { removed  }

        Fieldable field2 = new Fieldable() {also removed}

        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(field1);
        document.add(field2);
        List<Fieldable> minliste = document.getFields();

        indexWriter.addDocument(document); //this is where it fails
        }
```

Fieldable :

```
Fieldable field1 = new Fieldable()
        {

            @Override
            public int getBinaryLength() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getBinaryOffset() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBinaryValue() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBinaryValue(byte[] arg0) {

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public float getBoost() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getOmitNorms() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getOmitTermFreqAndPositions() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isBinary() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isIndexed() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLazy() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isStoreOffsetWithTermVector() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isStorePositionWithTermVector() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isStored() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isTermVectorStored() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isTokenized() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public String name() {
                //TODO
                return "path";
            }

            @Override
            public Reader readerValue() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void setBoost(float arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setOmitNorms(boolean arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setOmitTermFreqAndPositions(boolean arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public String stringValue() {
                //TODO
                return path;
            }

            @Override
            public TokenStream tokenStreamValue() {
                return null;
            }                   
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're implementing your `Fieldables` from scratch. I suspect that the problem is hidden somewhere in your removed lines - maybe one of the implemented methods return `null` where it should return a real value.

1. Try to add instances of `Field` instead and check if you still have the same error
2. Use a debugger an add a breakpoint on `NullPointerException`, that should help finding the *real* cause of your problem.

---

Now that you've added the implementation of your `Fieldable` I'm pretty sure that the NPE occurs because you return some `null` values in your implementation.

A hot candidate is your implementation of `readerValue()` which returns `null`. JavaDoc explains, that the `Reader` that is returned by this method can be used at index time to generate index tokens. An *indexing* is what happens automatically when you add more then one `Fieldable` to a document.

Give this a try:

```
@Override
public Reader readerValue() {
     return new StringReader(path);
}
```

Change your implementation and **avoid** return `null` unless the JavaDoc clearly says, that `null` is a legal return value.

(and: even if `Field` is deprecated: use it for a test to see, if the problem is related to your `Fieldables`. If your code works with `Field` objects, then you know where to look)

Comment: Field has been drepecated for Fieldable, i've debugged at stepped through the process, and confirmed that the document isn't null, and it contains the fieldables.
i've added the code for the Fieldable just in case.

Comment: update, followed your advice and went back to Fields, and just ignore the deprecation warnings. it works this way, but i'm still a bit frustrated that i can't figure out what's going on with fieldables.

Comment: Easy as I wrote: Something inside the lucene framework (indexer I guess) calls methods on your `Fieldables`, expects a value but receives `null`, tries to use `null` as an objects and runs into an NPE. Look at my last edit, added some code.

Comment: that doesn't make sense to me, when it doesn't fail until i add more than one fieldable to the document. i tried changing the two null returning methods in fieldable to return som muck data, got the same error.

Comment: It makes sense. Look at the JavaDoc for [Document#add](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html). Lucene will index *if* you add more then one `Fieldable`. On the other hand, no indexing if you only add one.